# How do I set activity backstack on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to set the onBackPress button to start activities that started before orderly. If I don't finish activities that started before when I start another activity, I can show the activity that started before with finish() current activity. This is possible. Because I don't finish any activity. So finish() current activity will cause show activity that started before. But, RAM will be overload when I open 50 activities may be. So because of this problem I need to finish() activity that started before. On the other hand, I want to start the activity that started before orderly when clicking to the back button. For example

```
   ActivityA --> ActivityB --> ActivityC --> ActivityD
```

In this scenario, I finish ActivityA, ActivityB, ActivityC orderly. But I want to start ActivityC back press of the ActivityD and I want to start ActivityB on the back press of ActivityC.

Lastly, I have a complex path in the application. And, I navigate to the ActivityD and I finished the ActivityF when my current activity is ActivityF

```
 ActivityF --> ActivityD
 ActivityF finished
```

Current activity:

```
 ActivityD
```

In this scenario, I want to start the ActivityF not the ActivityC on back button of the ActivityD.

Normally:

```
 ActivityA --> ActivityB --> ActivityC --> ActivityD /// click back button
 ActivityA --> ActivityB --> ActivityC /// click back button
 ActivityA --> ActivityB /// click back button
 ActivityA
```

or

```
 ActivityA --> ActivityF --> ActivityD /// click back button
 ActivityA --> ActivityF /// click back button
 ActivityA
```

But I want to generate this scenario:

```
 ActivityA
 --> ActivityB
 --> ActivityC
 --> ActivityD /// click back button
 ActivityC <-- /// click back button
 ActivityB <-- /// click back button
 ActivityA
```

or

```
 ActivityA
 --> ActivityF
 --> ActivityD /// click back button
 ActivityF <-- /// click back button
 ActivityA <--
```

**Update:**

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393100/how-do-i-go-back-to-the-finished-activity-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

In Activity A do this,

```
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class));
    finish();
```

This will finish `ActivityA` when moving to Activity B.

Next, in `ActivityB` override the `onBackPressed` in your Activity class and use an intent to revert to the previous activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class));
finish();
}
```

**NOTE:**

> If you do not override `onBackPressed` then it will go to the Activity before `ActivityA` (if not available exit from the app).

Links that might help you on getting started with Activity lifecycle:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle
- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: But this code will cause to RAM overloading when I browse in the app about 1 hour, 30 activities etc. :(

Comment: finish the activity when you are moving from activity A to activity B like you said and use this.

Comment: This is the simple activity passing to another activity. The question is not this.

Comment: @K.tas yup. have you heard about `onBackPressed`? See my updated answer..

Comment: "But this code will cause to RAM overloading when I browse in the app about 1 hour, 30 activities etc. :(" - explain how? There will be only one Activity running.

Comment: If I open an Activity and another one and another one at the end there will be many activities. For example, I am browsing on instagram for about 2 hours. open another person's profile page another one etc. if Instagram wouldn't close before one this would cause high memory usage.

Comment: And that is why you call `finish()` to finish that particular activity..

Comment: I solved this problem about 6 months ago. You can check what I mean here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393100/how-do-i-go-back-to-the-finished-activity-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(F.this, A.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

or

```
Intent i = new Intent(F.this, A.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: I want to keep track of before activity. Can you look at the question again? I don't want to simply pass one activity to another

Comment: For example, user passed between activities A to B. Now finish A and pass B to C, then finish B. Then click to the back button and go B again. Because B is the activity that the user comes from to current(ActivityC) activity.

Comment: If the user go to the C from A directly, then finish A. If press the back button, then goes to the A again. Because A is the activity that the user comes from to current(ActivityC) activity.