# How do I go back to the finished activity dynamically?

Tags: android

For example, user passed between activities A to B. Now finish A and pass B to C, then finish B. Then click to the back button and go B again. Because B is the activity that the user comes from to current(ActivityC) activity.If the user go to the C from A directly, then finish A. If press the back button, then goes to the A again. Because A is the activity that the user comes from to current(ActivityC) activity.
   I want to set the onBackPress button to start activities that started before orderly. If I don't finish activities that started before when I start another activity, I can show the activity that started before with finish() current activity. This is possible. Because I don't finish any activity. So finish() current activity will cause show activity that started before. But, RAM will be overload when I open 50 activities may be. So because of this problem I need to finish() activity that started before. On the other hand, I want to start the activity that started before orderly when clicking to the back button. For example

```
  ActivityA --> ActivityB --> ActivityC --> ActivityD
```

In this scenario, I finish ActivityA, ActivityB, ActivityC orderly. But I want to start ActivityC back press of the ActivityD and I want to start ActivityB on the back press of ActivityC.

Lastly, I have a complex path in the application. And, I navigate to the ActivityD and I finished the ActivityF when my current activity is ActivityF

```
ActivityF --> ActivityD
ActivityF finished
```

Current activity:

```
ActivityD
```

In this scenario, I want to start the ActivityF not the ActivityC on back button of the ActivityD.

Normally:

```
ActivityA --> ActivityB --> ActivityC --> ActivityD /// click back button
ActivityA --> ActivityB --> ActivityC /// click back button
ActivityA --> ActivityB /// click back button
ActivityA
```

or

```
ActivityA --> ActivityF --> ActivityD /// click back button
ActivityA --> ActivityF /// click back button
ActivityA
```

But I want to generate this scenario:

```
ActivityA
--> ActivityB
--> ActivityC
--> ActivityD /// click back button
ActivityC <-- /// click back button
ActivityB <-- /// click back button
ActivityA
```

or

```
ActivityA
--> ActivityF
--> ActivityD /// click back button
ActivityF <-- /// click back button
ActivityA <--
```

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Stack` to keep track of your Activities.
[Stack in Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Stack)

Just push the current Activity before Intent to next Activity, and pop the current Activity in the `onBackPressed()` method.

You can save the `Stack` on `SharedPreference`.

**EDIT:**

This is the code. I used a DataHandler class to save the `Stack`.

DataHandler.java

```
public class DataHandler {
private static DataHandler mDataHandler;
private Deque<Intent> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();

private DataHandler() {
}

public static DataHandler getInstance(){
    if(mDataHandler == null){
        mDataHandler = new DataHandler();
    }
    return mDataHandler;
}

public Deque<Intent> getStack() {
    return stack;
}

public void setStack(Deque<Intent> stack) {
    this.stack = stack;
}
}
```

M1Activity.java

```
public class M1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_m1);
    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(M1Activity.this,M2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            DataHandler.getInstance().getStack().push(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (DataHandler.getInstance().getStack().size() > 0){
        Intent intent = DataHandler.getInstance().getStack().pop();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Just like M1Activity, you have to push and pop intent from `Stack` in every `Activity`.

Comment: I think your answer is correct but how can I implement the this idea? Do you have any example code?

Comment: @K.tas I just developed it... I will post after verifying it.

Comment: @K.tas please check the updated Answer and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @K.tas anytime buddy... Whenever you reach 15 reputation you can upvote it... Happy Coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {           
   finish();
 } else {
   ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(RatingReviewActivity.this);
 }
```

Comment: what about onBackPressed? How can I use this code block I didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass ActivityA (Parent Activity) name to ActivityB (Child Activity) to keep reference of parent activity and use it in `onBackPressed` method need for starting parent activity.

When starting activity:

```
private void startActivity(){
    Intent intent =new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.putExtra("parentClassName",this.getClass().getName());
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

In child activity :

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

    String parentClassName;

    //..

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        parentClassName = getIntent().getExtras().get("parentClassName").toString();

        //..
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName(parentClassName));
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        }

        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is useful but If there is more than one tail. For example, A to B, B to C, C to D. And with your code I can only access Activity C. How can I go back more than one by this way

Comment: You will need to use this method in every activity. That way each activity will keep track of it parent activity.

Comment: Okay. But this is available only passing between two activity, not more. I cannot go back two step correctly. The second step will go back to again last activity. Because I am getting parents name. For example, A to B, B to C, C to D and one onBackPressed take user to C and send onBackPressed will be clicked from C activity and it will start activity D not B. Because we take D's name